# Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Just very new at R - what am I missing ?
I feel it's something to do with the groups ? and the as.factor(name) ?

Thank you for pointing the mistake and the doc so I can read and learn

Chris

```
library("ggplot")

test <- tibble(
  name = c("TEAMA", "TEAMA", "TEAMA", "TEAMB", "TEAMB"),
  percent = c(22.4, 18.8, 43.5, 25.5, 13.8),
  eff = c(.36, .62, .43, .16, .08),
  groups = factor(c("f","f","b","f","b"), levels = c("f","b")),
  col = c(1,2,1,1,1)
)
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=percent, y=eff, color=as.factor(name))) +
  facet_grid(groups ~ col) +  
  stat_density_2d()
```

gives me

```
Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`:
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
2: Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`:
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
3: Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`:
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
4: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In max(f) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: You have groups with fewer than two data points and those are dropped. The result is `max` returning `-Inf`. Try without faceting and see what happens.

Comment: Ohhhh I want faceting but I see what you mean - let me check if there is a way to NOT drop the data points